# Использование enum в конструкциях switch

Tags: c#, .net

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста, вот есть переменная типа enum. Как известно enum не преобразуется автоматически в целочисленный тип. Но почему тогда с помощью переменной этого типа есть возможность управлять циклом for или switch? При этом указывать без явного приведения типов переменную enum в качестве индекса массива нельзя. Как это понять?

Answer (score 8):

MSDN нам говорит, что **"По умолчанию базовым типом каждого элемента перечисления является int. Можно задать другой целочисленный тип, используя двоеточие"**. Следовательно, для enum также доступнны операции инкремента, декремента, операторы сравнения и прочие замечатеьлные операторы. Но что еще более важно, это значит, что **enum** может быть использован в качестве счетчика в цикле **for**:

```
enum Foo
{
    First, 
    Second, 
    Third
}

for(FooEn f = FooEn.First; f != FooEn.Third; f++ )
    Console.WriteLine(f);
```

Что же касается оператора **switch**, то для него совсем не обязательно использовать **int**. Например, он может получать строки. В общем-то для сравнения двух значений вовсе не обязательно, чтобы эти значения обязательно были целыми числами